# c++ interpretation of make/compile error gnu compiler

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run a c++ program on an external computer running Linux, but I have problems with compiling. The program compiles fine in Visual Studio Code on my personal Mac...

My knowledge of programming and computer is somewhat limited, but I believe the computer uses a GNU compiler, and after some googling. At least it uses something different than VS Code on my mac, as I had to alter the Makefile.

When I use the command "make" to build my program (which consists of several .h and .cpp files), I get some errors that I don't know how to resolve, but I assume it has something to do with my two classes "Subproblem" and "Label" (see the bottom of this post for error code)

Both classes have member functions that take the other in as an argument. Thus I've used a forward declaration of the Subproblem-class before the definition of my Label-class. Here's a simplified version of my code in Label.h, including the functions that are referenced in the error message:

```
#pragma once
#include "Duals.h" 
#include "Nodes.h"
#include <memory> 
#include <iostream>


class Subproblem; // forward declaration

class Label : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Label> {
    // private members
public:
    Label();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node> > const PossibleMoves(Subproblem* const sp, int startLB, int startUB, int endLB, int endUB);
    std::shared_ptr<Label> ExtendLabel(std::shared_ptr<Node> destinationNode, Subproblem* const sp, Duals duals); 
};

bool CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label> l1, std::shared_ptr<Label> l2); 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<Label> l);

bool operator< (const std::shared_ptr<Label>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Label>& rhs);
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be the problem and how I can resolve it? I'm using c++17 and g++. I'm new to this forum so sorry if something is unclear or missing from my description.

```
g++ -std=c++17   -c -o Subproblem.o Subproblem.cpp
g++ -o program.exe -I/share/apps/gurobi/9.5.1/include/  main.o BBnode.o BBtree.o Heuristic.o Label.o    MasterProblem.o Nodes.o Pattern.o       Solution.o      Subproblem.o    TestInstance.o Utilities.o -lm -L/share/apps/gurobi/9.5.1/lib -lgurobi_g++5.2  -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95  
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: Label.o:1:1: invalid character
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'Label::PossibleMoves(Subproblem*, int, int, int, int)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::ostream&, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'Label::ExtendLabel(std::shared_ptr<Node>, Subproblem*, Duals)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::ostream&, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::ostream&, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::ostream&, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function Subproblem::FindPaths(Duals, int, int, int, int): error: undefined reference to 'CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::shared_ptr<Label>)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >) const: error: undefined reference to 'operator<(std::shared_ptr<Label> const&, std::shared_ptr<Label> const&)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_less_iter::operator()<std::shared_ptr<Label>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > > >(std::shared_ptr<Label>&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >) const: error: undefined reference to 'operator<(std::shared_ptr<Label> const&, std::shared_ptr<Label> const&)'
Subproblem.o:Subproblem.cpp:function bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_val::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >, std::shared_ptr<Label> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Label>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Label>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Label> > > >, std::shared_ptr<Label>&) const: error: undefined reference to 'operator<(std::shared_ptr<Label> const&, std::shared_ptr<Label> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program.exe] Error 1
```

This is my Makefile:

```
   CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++17

src = $(wildcard *.cpp)
obj = $(src:.cpp=.o)
dep = $(obj:.o=.d)

LDFLAGS += -lm -L$(GUROBI_HOME)/lib -lgurobi_g++5.2  -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95  

CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH += -I$(GUROBI_HOME)/include/ 

all: program.exe

program.exe : main.o BBnode.o BBtree.o Heuristic.o Label.o  MasterProblem.o Nodes.o Pattern.o   Solution.o  Subproblem.o    TestInstance.o  Utilities.o
    $(CXX) -o program.exe $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) main.o BBnode.o BBtree.o Heuristic.o Label.o    MasterProblem.o Nodes.o Pattern.o   Solution.o  Subproblem.o    TestInstance.o  Utilities.o $(LDFLAGS)

    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) BBnode.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) BBtree.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Heuristic.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Label.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) MasterProblem.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Nodes.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Pattern.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Solution.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Subproblem.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) TestInstance.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
    #$(CXX) -c $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) Utilities.cpp $(LDFLAGS)



-include $(dep)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f VRPTW.exe $(obj)

.PHONY: cleandep
cleandep:
    rm -f $(dep)
```

Content of Label.cpp:

```
#include #include "Label.h"
#include "Subproblem.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node> > const 

Label::PossibleMoves(Subproblem* const sp, int startLB, int startUB, int endLB, int endUB) { /* implementation */ }

std::shared_ptr<Label> Label::ExtendLabel(std::shared_ptr<Node> destinationNode, Subproblem* const sp, Duals duals){ /* implementation */ }

bool CheckDominance(std::shared_ptr<Label> l1, std::shared_ptr<Label> l2){ /* implementation */}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::shared_ptr<Label> l){ /* implementation */}

bool operator< (const std::shared_ptr<Label>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Label>& rhs){ /* implementation*/ }
```

Comment: You're not building with all *source* files.

Comment: what does this mean? What should I do?

Comment: How did you compile `Label.cpp` and what are the contents of that file? The linker is complaining that some function definitions (which are probably supposed to be in there) could not be found in any of the listed `.o` files.

Comment: Will the makefile help answer that question? I added it to my original post now. I'm very new to programming, so I get confused about what everything means.

And the Label.cpp contains the implementation of the functions defined in Label.h.

Comment: $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) in linker command `$(CXX) -o program.exe $(CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH) ...` is unnecessary and unused. It should rather be in compile line, which you don't have in your Makefile. Ho does it compile anything?

Comment: Again I must say that I am new to this and don't really know how makefiles work... What is "compile line", and what specifically should I write (and where)?

Comment: _What is "compile line"_ - you don't have it defined but it works automagically as make does that for you. You heve nowhere defined how you compile .cpp into .o although you have how to link (`$(CXX) -o program.exe ...`)

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks! so how do I define how to compile from .cpp to .o?

Comment: As I said it works automagically

Comment: Then I don't think I understand.. How do I get my program to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at the error messages, you will see that there is a difference in arguments. For example, the error that complains about `Label::PossibleMoves(Subproblem*, int, int, int, int)` takes a `Subproblem*`, not a `Subproblem *const` as written in your header and implementation file.

This makes me think that you're linking with an older version of `Subproblem.o`, which hasn't been recompiled after you made some changes to `Label.cpp` and `Label.h`.

This makes sense, because the `Makefile` relies on an *implicit* rule about how to make a `.o` from a `.cpp`, and the implicit rule assumes that the `.o` *only* depends on the `.cpp`. It does not scan the included headers to see if anything changed there; that task is normally done by some makefile generator like autotools or CMake, or manually written into the `Makefile` itself.

In the old version of the `Makefile` rule for `program.exe` (commented out), there were a bunch of `$(CXX)` invocations that would recompile every `.cpp` every time something changed. A simple but crude solution.

If you just need to compile this once and get on with your life, try removing all `.o` files and building from scratch. I suspect you'll get rid of these errors (and maybe get exciting new ones in return).

If you need a proper solution, look into CMake or some other makefile generator or build tool that does detect dependencies between source files.

Comment: With proper Makefile it ("old" objects) should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with the original Q, but unfortunately, I'm still getting errors... Now it tells me that there is an error in the Subproblem.cpp file: `error: ?Label? was not declared in this scope`. Even though I have written `#include "Label.h"` at the top the file.

Comment: @tansy Exactly my point -- this is not a proper Makefile.

Comment: @lea If you haven't figured it out yet by now, open a new question with the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer yet but try to use this Makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++17 -O2 -g

INCLUDES = -I$(GUROBI_HOME)/include

srcs = $(wildcard *.cpp)
objs = $(srcs:.cpp=.o)
deps = $(objs:.o=.d)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

GUROBI_HOME=gurobi52

LIBS = -lm -L$(GUROBI_HOME)/lib -lgurobi_g++5.2  -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95 
LDFLAGS =


all: program

program : $(objs)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)


-include $(dep)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(objs)

.PHONY: cleandep

cleandep:
    rm -f $(deps)
```

Hopefully it's more legible and start from that.

Automatic variables in link `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)` is equivalent to `$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o program $(objs) $(LIBS)`.

Reading the answer from @Thomas, you need to clean it with `$ make clean`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the following: `make: *** No rule to make target 'bb.o', needed by 'program'.  Stop.`

Comment: And how about now?

Comment: Now I get a lot of "undefined reference to" errors related to functions in the gurobi library

Comment: You have to edit `LIBS` variable with your libs, namely `LIBS = -lm -L$(GUROBI_HOME)/lib -lgurobi_g++5.2  -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95 `

Comment: If I change to `LIBS = -lm -L$(GUROBI_HOME)/lib -lgurobi_g++5.2  -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi95`, I'm back to the original error messages

Comment: `$ make clean` like in (edited) answer. This should clean your old objects and then you can compile it a new.

Comment: If you can't find it now then you have to read and make [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I don't think I'm competent enough to manage to make such a small example that reproduces the same errors... However, Thomas did solve my original problem, so I can try to do some more research for myself on the new errors :)